# I'm trying to make an on-screen keyboard with Tkinter but when I try to create the keyboard class, it gives me a TypeError

Tags: python, object, tkinter

When I run this python code it throws the error "TypeError: place_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". I imported Tkinter using the line "from tkinter import *".

```
class Keyboard:
    def __init__(self, posX, posY, keySize, keyColor, letterColor):
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
        self.keySize = keySize
        self.keyColor = keyColor
        self.letterColor = letterColor
        for i in range(0, 26):
            for j in range(0, 10):
                Button(text=keys[i], command=lambda: KeyPress(keys[i]))
                Button.place(x=(posX*j)+keySize, y=posY)
            
keyboard = Keyboard(10, 10, 10, "white", "black")
```

Comment: You need to call `.place(...)` on an instance of widget: `btn = Button(...)` and then `btn.place(...)`.

Comment: And also, better to use `grid()`. Even better is to create a layout of your own and then loop through that layout(perhaps a 2d list).

Answer (score 0):

As acw1668 mentions, `.place()` needs to be used, but I also noticed that your nested loop was causing it to generate buttons with only 'z'. Here's an adjusted version of your script that correctly lists the full alphabet. Note that i've just used `string.ascii_lowercase` to generate a list since you didn't include `keys` in your minimum reproduction.

```
from tkinter import *
import string  # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys

root = Tk()


class Keyboard:
    def __init__(self, posx, posy, keysize, keycolor, lettercolor):
        self.posX = posx
        self.posY = posy
        self.keySize = keysize
        self.keyColor = keycolor
        self.letterColor = lettercolor

        # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys
        keys = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]

        for i in range(0, 26):
            button = Button(text=keys[i])
            button.place(x=(posx * i) + keysize, y=posy)


keyboard = Keyboard(10, 10, 10, "white", "black")

root.mainloop()
```

Regarding the way you're placing the buttons, you might want to refer to `grid()` for the sake of simplicity. Here's an example of your code converted to `grid()`, with added `sticky` and `weight`.

```
from tkinter import *
import string  # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys

root = Tk()


class Keyboard:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Colour Variables
        self.keyColor = "white"
        self.letterColor = "black"

        # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys
        keys = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]

        for i in range(0, 26):
            self.master.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.button = Button(self.master, text=keys[i])
            self.button.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky='EW')

keyboard = Keyboard(root)

root.mainloop()
```